# Why will my SVG background file not scale up?

Tags: svg, background, size

My problem is that the browser does not listen to `background-size`. I even tried to set `preserveAspectRatio` to `none` in the SVG but it still does not work.

It should not resize with aspect ratio. Stretching out is fine..

**SVG file**

To have it a background image in my example, I use a `data:image`. If you want to know what the SVG file looks like, it's here below:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M 10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10" fill="000"/>
</svg>
```

### Example

What I expect is that black "banana" to change size to something bigger. I set it to 100px so it should span all the way to the end of the div.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpath d='M 10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10' fill='000'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-position: center 0;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Add a `viewBox` to the svg element for example `viewBox='10 10 40 7.5'`

Comment: What is "it" as in "I set *it* to 100px"? The width, the height, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your SVG will take any width or height, and your `path` is in a fixed position and size, no CSS will do the trick because the scaling won't do anything. Instead, add a `viewBox` to your SVG. Your SVG will now look like this.

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="10 10 40 7.5">
  <path d="M 10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10" fill="000"/>
</svg>
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1_W7AIhdfiwxgU0_FrTsYwyVrZvjzxt18&export=download");
  background-position: center 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

By the way, the drive file background image is just the svg.

Answer (score 1):

A viewbox is needed. Thanks to @enxaneta.

```
viewBox='10 10 40 7.5'
```